# Scalar field Bulk propagator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, greens-functions, propagator, ads-cft

For a massless scalar field in $AdS_{d+1}$ the bulk propagator is
\begin{align*}
\Box_{\vec x, z} K_B(\vec x, z;\vec x') = \delta^{d} (\vec x - \vec x')
\end{align*}
if the solution to $K_B$ is
\begin{equation}
K_B(\vec x, z;\vec x') = \frac{\Gamma(\Delta)}{\pi^{d/2} \Gamma (\Delta-d/2)}(\frac{z}{z^2+(\vec x - \vec x')^2})^\Delta. 
\end{equation}

How can we put this $K_B$ in the equation and conclude that $\Delta = d$?

How did we find this solution to $K_B$?

Comment: The best way is to go to $d + 2$ dimensions and show that the propagator is some really simple $(X \cdot Y)^\Delta$ before you pull it back to a hyperboloid. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04948 for details.